# How to style the microphone of the Google Chrome speech input control

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, styles

Google Chrome has the following input control:

[image]

More info on how to use it can be found [here](http://www.labnol.org/software/add-speech-recognition-to-website/19989/).

I need to make the microphone bigger. It would also be nice if I could use a custom image for the microphone. I found that adjusting the width and height of the input element does not make the microphone larger.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#speech {
  -webkit-transform: scale(4,4)
}
```

This is what I worked out:

and the html for that is:[image]

```
<html>
    <body>
        <img src="Capture.JPG" alt="Smiley face" width="80" style="margin-top:70px; margin-left:120px; position:absolute;"  />
        <input style="-webkit-transform: scale(8,8); opacity:.001; width:50px; border:none; margin-left:00px; margin-top:100px;"  type="text" speech="speech" x-webkit-speech="x-webkit-speech"  />          
    </body>
</html>
```

[image]

anyways now I could use the events:

```
 onspeechchange="processspeech();"  
 onwebkitspeechchange="processspeech();"
```

to place the text where appropriate...

Answer (score 1):

Currently, the only way to increase the size of the microphone is to increase the `font-size` of the input element.

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="speech" value="some text here" x-webkit-speech />
```

CSS:

```
#speech {
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

Comment: I remember that there was a site that used it's own big microphone. I will keep looking. That helps though so thanks

Answer (score 0):

For people still looking for this: I managed to style it by setting the opacity of the speech element to 0, then overlaying it with a visible element that you can style yourself. Then I used jQuery to trigger a click on the speech element when you click on your overlayed element :) This way you can even use your own image!

As a note, as far as I know there will be an edited version of the W3C spec for the speech element in the future, that should give developers more control over the look and feel (source: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/html5/articles/voice-to-drive-the-web-introduction-to-speech-api.html)

Answer (score 0):

In Webkit you can enter the [shadow DOM](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/shadowdom/) to alter the layout of default browser elements. This is how I did it using a custom icon font from [icomoon.io](http://icomoon.io/app/) (font "Font Awesome" has a nice microphone), but you can of course also use any background image on the `input::-webkit-input-speech-button` element itself.

```
input::-webkit-input-speech-button {
  -webkit-appearance: none; /* Important to undo default styling. */
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0 1em;
  cursor: pointer;

  &:before {
    content: '\e601';
    font-family: icomoon;
  }
}
```